# ElasticFox on Firefox 4

Tags: firefox, amazon-ec2, aws

How are you supposed to install the **ElasticFox** add-on on Firefox (4.0.1) on latest Ubuntu (11.04)? (ElasticFox is an extension for Amazon EC2 management.)

Going to Tools -> Add-ons and searching for it returns nothing. Top results for ["install elasticfox firefox 4"](http://www.google.fi/#sclient=psy&hl=fi&source=hp&q=install+elasticfox+firefox+4&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=80ae73819be78557) search are strange links that just throw me back to browser's home page. [Apparently](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=233704) people who had it installed before upgrading to Firefox 4 have got it working, but how about us who don't have it yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to our awesome [George Edison](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/george-edison) I was able to modify that plugin to make it work with Firefox 4.0.1. Thanks again for pointing that out!

Here is the modified [plugin](http://ubuntuone.com/p/uOO/).

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to install Firefox 3.x via Ubuntu package management (perhaps alongside 4.0)?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.